# git repository sharing between users

Tags: git

Is it possible in Git for a user to do pull and read from other users repository on the same server at the same location. Say I have a NFS mount which is accessible to both the users and I have two users A and B having access to a common directory location. User A has cloned a repository X, and I dont want user B to create another repository but use user A's repository. Can User B pull (i.e to refresh User A's repository) and read from that repository of User A. Requirement is that User B will not have to created his own repository but use User A's repository. I am using Stash.

Comment: "Requirement is that User B will not have to created his own repository" -- that's plainly not your real requirement.  How about saying what you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the same machine then you just simply synchronized same folder for both the user. Still you can keep track of changes through git. To share the folder you don't need to have run git. That would be a feasible step. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks, How would I synchronize the folder? I always want to do pull and then use it for whatever purpose for both the users.

Comment: I understand your query. you can pull it through network but if you just need to track the changes (and you are the single user operating) then I would suggest to share the folder for both the user and keep track of the changes only (using git).