# Share Git object-repository between users

Tags: git

[ Note: this is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112974/git-repository-sharing-between-users because I want users to have their own clone, I just want to share the underlying object database. ]

I have a fairly large Git repository accessed by various users on the same machine.
Is it possible to avoid having every user have its own copy of the repository's objects?

I tried to use `git clone --reference ~otheruser/foo ...` which seems to work to some extent, but then `git gc` gives me a warning:

```
$ git gc
Enumerating objects: 339704, done.
Counting objects: 100% (4611/4611), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2442/2442), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4611/4611), done.
Total 4611 (delta 2164), reused 4611 (delta 2164), pack-reused 0
Checking connectivity: 339728, done.
warning: unable to unlink '/home/otheruser/foo/.git/objects/pack/pack-88be8eadb55c04690096008a883d76835ddbf24c.idx': Permission denied
warning: unable to unlink '/home/otheruser/foo/.git/objects/pack/pack-af141b07e139a664364d08873cc23598a021ecdf.idx': Permission denied
Expanding reachable commits in commit graph: 82246, done.
$
```

Should I worry about it (I'm already fully aware of the risks associated with the use of `--reference`, so I'm talking here more specifically about the situation where the `.git/objects/info/alternates` points to a directory belonging to some other user).

[ To be honest, I'm actually surprised that Git would try to remove files in the "alternate" object-repository, regardless if it belongs to some other user.  ]

Comment: It does seem ... odd for Git to try to unlink a pack file in an alternate directory. This could well be a bug.

Comment: What's your OS ?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux.  I wonder why that would make a difference

Comment: @Stefan did you find a solution? We have hundred of users in a shared FS, and the situatiion of every user recloning >3GB repo is borderline ridiculous

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich: There was no real problem, apparently.  The warnings seem harmless.

Answer (score 0):

You can make separate branch for every user, and store this branches working directory in separate directories using [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) command.

Comment: No, I don't want to share the actual Git repositories: only the object store (I don't want users to have to worry about stepping on each other's toes that much).  I'm already using worktrees extensively, but in any case I don't think this can work, because it would mean the users would share the complete Git repository so I'd have to make it writable by both users and I don't want to do that.

Comment: I understand now. What is your use case, maybe you want workaround something what is standard and supported solution